# ggvis with shiny runtime produces inconsistent output on EC2

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, shiny, r-markdown, ggvis

I'm creating a configurable, interactive report with Rmarkdown, Shiny and ggvis. I develop on a Mac, then deploy to a Shiny server running Ubuntu on EC2. On EC2, my reactive ggvis plots fail to render, and instead just echo the reactive code:
[image]

Locally, I have no problems rendering the reactive plot:

[image]

Has anyone seen this before? What's causing the inconsistent behavior?

Self-contained example here:

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r config}
require(ggvis)

inputPanel(selectInput('dataset', 'Data Set:', c('one', 'the other')),
           actionButton('run', 'Run!'))

data = eventReactive(input$run, {
  if (input$dataset == 'one') {
    data = data.frame(x = 1:20, y = rnorm(20))
  } else {
    data = data.frame(x = 1:20, y = rnorm(20, mean = 10, sd = 10))
  }
  return(data)
})  
```

```{r plot}
reactive({
  data() %>%
    ggvis(x = ~x, y = ~y) %>%
    layer_points(size := input_slider(min = 1, max = 100)) %>%
    bind_shiny('plot', 'plot_ui')
})

uiOutput('plot_ui')
ggvisOutput('plot')
```
````

Comment: It works locally and on [shinyapp.io](https://hleviel.shinyapps.io/test/)

Comment: Right, that's kind of the problem. It works locally, but not on an EC2 shiny server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to produce the correct output by wrapping everything into a Shiny App.

````
```{r shiny-app}
require(ggvis)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    inputPanel(selectInput('dataset', 'Data Set:', c('one', 'the other')),
           actionButton('run', 'Run!')),
    uiOutput('plot_ui'),
    ggvisOutput('plot')),

  server = function(input, output) {
    data = eventReactive(input$run, {
      if (input$dataset == 'one') {
        data = data.frame(x = 1:20, y = rnorm(20))
      } else {
        data = data.frame(x = 1:20, y = rnorm(20, mean = 10, sd = 10))
      }
      return(data)
    }) 

    output$plot = reactive({
      data() %>%
        ggvis(x = ~x, y = ~y) %>%
        layer_points(size := input_slider(min = 1, max = 100)) %>% 
        bind_shiny('plot', 'plot_ui')
    })
  },
  options = list(height = 500)
)
```
````

This fixes the problem, but is a little disappointing since a big selling point for using `ggvis` is not having to write a bunch of Shiny boilerplate. :< Still curious if this can be solved another route.